# mysql select information from two tables if second has match

Tags: mysql, sql

I got two tables. not every row connects with table2 but if they do id, supplier are the same. i want to select all records from table1 with query LIKE or match against, but it will only select if the suppliers are in table2 too. Any ideas?

```
table1
id          | 1
supplier    | 1
```

extra information table:

```
table2
id        | 1
supplier  | 1
extrainfo | "Best information"
```

query

```
SELECT
    table1.*,table2.*
FROM
    mytable_normalinfo as table1,
    mytable_extrainfo as table2
WHERE 
  MATCH(table1.fulltextcollum)
  AGAINST ('+test*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND
     table1.supplier =  table2.supplier 
AND
     table1.id = table2.id
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just want a `left join`:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.*
FROM mytable_normalinfo as table1 LEFT JOIN
     mytable_extrainfo as table2
     ON table1.supplier =  table2.supplier AND
        table1.id = table2.id
WHERE MATCH(table1.fulltextcollum) AGAINST ('+test*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
LIMIT 10;
```

Two notes:

- Learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- When you use `LIMIT`, normally you would also use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Thank you for the notes! I will use them properly.